# Clickhouse: Aggregate clickhouse timeseries starting from 9:15

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse table

```
time_stamp     DateTime(Asia/Kolkata)
value          Int32
```

I want to generate a timeseries from 9:15 to 23:15 with value being the first value in that range

i tried doing something like this

```
SELECT
    toStartOfInterval(time_stamp, INTERVAL 1 HOUR, 'Asia/Kolkata') AS ts,
    any(value)
FROM table hdqlm 
GROUP by ts
order by ts
```

`toStartOfInterval` rounds it to 9:00 AM which i dont want

```
2023-03-01 09:00:00.000 +0530   0
2023-03-01 10:00:00.000 +0530   0
2023-03-01 11:00:00.000 +0530   0
2023-03-01 12:00:00.000 +0530   0
2023-03-01 13:00:00.000 +0530   0
2023-03-01 14:00:00.000 +0530   0
2023-03-01 15:00:00.000 +0530   0
```

I tried the below query where im forcing the group by to be between 9:!5 to 23:15

```
SELECT
    ts,
    any(value)
FROM table 
GROUP by addMinutes(toStartOfInterval(time_stamp, INTERVAL 1 HOUR, 'Asia/Kolkata'), 15) AS ts
order by ts
```

while i do get a better output

```
2023-03-01 09:15:00.000 +0530   128790
2023-03-01 10:15:00.000 +0530   128790
2023-03-01 11:15:00.000 +0530   129334
2023-03-01 12:15:00.000 +0530   129195
2023-03-01 13:15:00.000 +0530   129765
2023-03-01 14:15:00.000 +0530   129409
2023-03-01 15:15:00.000 +0530   129345
```

the problem here is the aggregates is still being performed from the start of the hour - i.e from 9:00 to 10:00, from 10:00 to 11:00 etc

can I use something else to ensure the aggregates are performed from the 15th minute?

My data starts from 9:15 - there is no 9:00 am data - hence why i want to group from 9:15 to 23:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
create table agg(t DateTime) Engine=Memory
as select toDateTime('2020-01-01 08:45:00')+number*1800 from numbers(24);

SELECT
    toStartOfHour(toStartOfInterval(t, interval 15 minute) - interval 15 minute)+interval 15 minute ts,
    count() cnt
FROM agg
GROUP by ts
order by ts

┌──────────────────ts─┬─cnt─┐
│ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │   1 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 10:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 11:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 12:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 13:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 14:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 15:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 16:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 17:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 18:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 19:15:00 │   2 │
│ 2020-01-01 20:15:00 │   1 │
└─────────────────────┴─────┘
```

---

Let's compare 2 formulas

```sql
SELECT
    toDateTime('2020-01-01 08:14:00') + (number * 600) AS t,
    toStartOfHour(toStartOfInterval(t, toIntervalMinute(15)) - toIntervalMinute(15)) + toIntervalMinute(15) AS main,
    addMinutes(toStartOfInterval(t, toIntervalHour(1)), 15) AS yours,
    main = yours AS comp
FROM numbers(10)

┌───────────────────t─┬────────────────main─┬───────────────yours─┬─comp─┐
│ 2020-01-01 08:14:00 │ 2020-01-01 07:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │    0 │
│ 2020-01-01 08:24:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │    1 │
│ 2020-01-01 08:34:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │    1 │
│ 2020-01-01 08:44:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │    1 │
│ 2020-01-01 08:54:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │    1 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:04:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │    0 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:14:00 │ 2020-01-01 08:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │    0 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:24:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │    1 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:34:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │    1 │
│ 2020-01-01 09:44:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │ 2020-01-01 09:15:00 │    1 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: This roughly seems to work - thanks  :)

Comment: if you could, would you mind explaining why it works? doesnt mine result in the same query response?

Comment: I added the comparison. How I can explain basic arithmetic? I cannot.